# MDX - last level in tuple - SSRS Query Designer

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I have such hierarchy of certain group in my cube (here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OD4b.jpg):

```
1. Group    
1a. Group  
    +Members  
    +Level 02  
    +Level 03  
    +Level 04  
    *Member properties  
    *a  
    *b  
    *c  
    *d
```

And I'm wondering how to display only the last level of this group. Because when I write`[Group]` I'll have all members from all levels. The main condition is that I don't know that the last level is `Level 04` (there could be more than 4 levels).

Is there any function which I should know?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **hierarchy.levels.count** to get the number of levels in the hierarchy when you have a hierarchy with an unknown/changing number of levels. From there you can get the lowest level with the **Levels** function. You have to subtract one because it is a zero-based position.

```
[Group].[Group].Levels([Group].[Group].levels.count-1)
```

You can also do this with **Descendants** . The second argument in the descendants function is a distance from the specified member so you have to subtract 1 from the levels count. Here's an example query.

```
select {} on 0, 
descendants([Group].[Group].[All], ([Group].[Group].levels.count - 1), SELF) on 1
from [Cube]
```

One note: if you have a ragged hierarchy (which I am guessing you do since you don't know the number of levels), this is only going to pull the members at the lowest level rather than all leaves. If you are using hidememberif to hide repeating members so they are not their own parent, what you really need is all leaves, which you can specify that in the descendants function.

```
select {} on 0, 
    descendants([Group].[Group].[All], , LEAVES) on 1
    from [Cube]
```

Comment: The second query is the best as for me, because the third query gives me all leaves from all levels. For example I have such situation that in `Level 02` I have also single leaf which will be also displayed - what I don't want.
    
But I have another question (maybe it is for another topic). I can get such situation only by using this code in Design Mode in SSRS. Is there any option to do this in Query Designer?